# How to specify inline keyframes in JavaScript passing a variable value?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have various notification elements of different sizes, and I slide them up and out after a timer. I need to know the size of the notification box to know how much to move it, so that the other notifications below it slide into place smoothly.

I would like to do something like

```
notificationEl.current.style = `@keyframes slideOut { 100% { margin-top: ${amountToMove}, opacity: 0}}`;
```

but it doesn't work. I tried instead using Element.animate() inside the useEffect on mount, but this causes weird flicker behavior.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  notificationEl.current.animate([{ opacity: 0 }, { marginTop: marginTop }], {
    animationTimingFunction: "ease-out",
    duration: 375,
  });
}, 2625);
```

Is there a way closer to the first example that I can assign a variable to margin-top inside the keyframe? Ideally, I'd want to do this in the useEffect on mount.

A little more explanation:

There is a fixed position notifications container on the right with no inherit size. It gets populated by specific notifications that slide in from the right and are arranged in a column. When the topmost one slides out, the one's underneath should slide in to occupy the space left by the first one, and this should happen as the slideout animation for the first notification occurs, so it looks smooth. Using translate or "top" don't get the bottom ones to move up until the first one unmounts. Collapsing height isn't what I want either, as that affects the look of the notification that's making its way out.

I have to make the margin-top in the keyframe the size of the bounding client rect plus an offset (that's what amountToMove indicates) because the sizes of the notifications can and do vary so the amount to move them by in order to make the animation look smooth also varies.

Comment: Hi. May I ask you if the animation is mandatory? I would put a default transition time on the element and then work with the "top" property.

Comment: @Fabrizio Unfortunately, that would not work. I need to use margin-top because I need moving the element to affect the document flow.

Comment: How are the notification elements positioned?
Maybe some more code pieces would clarify how you made the flow.

Comment: @Fabrizio I'll try when I can get to it. There is a fixed position notifications container on the right with no inherit size. It gets populated by specific notifications that slide in from the right and are arranged in a column. When the topmost one slides out, the one's underneath should slide in to occupy the space left by the first one, and this should happen as the slideout animation for the first notification occurs, so it looks smooth. Using translate or top don't get the bottom ones to move up until the first one unmounts. Collapsing height isn't what I want either.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, a nice solution was using

```
notificationEl.current.style.setProperty("--marginTop", `${amountToMove}`);
```

and then in the stylesheet keyframes declaration, use the variable:

```
@keyframes slideOut {
  100% {
    margin-top: var(--marginTop);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```